# PHP File Upload with Apache Linux Server

Tags: php, apache, file-upload

I am having trouble uploading a file to my server. I am using another computer on my network at act as my server running Linux using Apache. I am trying to upload pdf files to my server but no matter what size or the name of the file I can not get a file to upload. When I `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` I get `/var/www`. My folder structured would be `var/www/phpfiles/uploads`. The files `addentry.php`, `phpupload.php` and `test.php` are all in this path `var/www/phpfiles`.

When I upload a file I get the correct file name, size and tmp echoed, but I do not get "Uploaded" or "Root Uploaded" echoed, and the file is not moved to `var/www/phpfiles/uploads`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

addentry.php

```
<div id="uploadPDF">
    <iframe id="iframe_display" src="test.php" width="400" height="100">

    </iframe>

</div>
```

phpupload.php

```
$tempName = $_POST[instrumentPDF];
$fileSize = $_FILES['instrumentPDF']['size'];
$fileType = $_FILES['instrumentPDF']['type'];
$fileName = $_FILES['instrumentPDF']['name'];
$tmp_name  = $_FILES['instrumentPDF']['tmp_name'];

echo ("file size: " . $fileSize  . "<br>");
    echo ("<br>");
    echo ("file name: " . $fileName . "<br>");
    echo ("<br>");
    echo ("pdf Test: " . $pdfTest . "<br>");
    echo ("<br>");
    echo ("pdf Temp_Name: " . $tmp_name . "<br>");

if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "uploads/" . $fileName)){
    echo ("<br>");
    echo ("Uploaded");
    echo ("<br>");
}

if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/".$fileName)){
    echo ("<br>");
    echo ("Root Uploaded");
    echo ("<br>");
}
```

test.php

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="phpupload.php" name="aform" id="PDFform">
    <table width="300" height="25" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td><label>Instrument (only pdf)</label> <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="104857600" /></td>
        <td><input name="instrumentPDF" type="file"  onchange="check_file()"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input name="Submit" type="Submit" align="absmiddle" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: It's usually got to do with permission of that dir. try to see if you have an error by `$_FILES["instrumentPDF"]["error"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Adidi - it usually has to do with permissions.  Here is another post about what permissions are proper for a folder that allows uploads: [What are the proper permissions for an upload folder with PHP/Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990/what-are-the-proper-permissions-for-an-upload-folder-with-php-apache)