# File Upload (works locally, but not on remote server)

Tags: php, apache, file, upload

I'm trying to upload a file (msword/doc) to a Apache server folder via an HTML form. It works when I test it locally (I'm testing it via MAMP), but when I upload it to a remote server (such as GoDaddy), it doesn't work. It shows "There was a problem with the file upload".

Below is the snippet of code that processes the file upload. I can't figure out what is wrong with my conditional.

```
      // Move the file to the target upload folder
      $target = FILE_UPLOADPATH . basename($new_file);
      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['new_file']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
      {
        // The new file move was successful, now make sure any old file is deleted
        if (!empty($old_file) && ($old_file != $new_file)) 
        {
          @unlink(FILE_UPLOADPATH . $old_file);
        }
      }
      else 
      {
        // The new file move failed, so delete the temporary file and set the error flag
        @unlink($_FILES['new_file']['tmp_name']);
        echo 'There was a problem with the file upload.' . PHP_EOL;
      }
```

Comment: Can you share the full $_FILES array, as the value in the error param may help shed some light on this

Comment: Here is the $_FILES array output: Array ( [new_file] => Array ( [name] => sample.doc [type] => msword/doc [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpsTu20P [error] => 0 [size] => 119674 )) Thoughts?

Comment: The value in the error parameter is 0.

Comment: Hmm, error 0 means success.

Comment: Comment out your @unlink call for now to ensure that the only thing tested is your upload, and post results.  Does the newly uploaded file still not appear in the directory

Comment: @kthaker What does `var_dump(is_writable($target));` give you?

Comment: The issue was with permissions. I didn't realize the server I was testing on had ACLs set up. So my chmod permissions changes didn't go through. Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

If `$_FILES['new_file']['error'] == 0` then the upload isn't the problem, but the call to `move_uploaded_file()` is. You probably have incorrect permissions on the directory you're trying to move the file to.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the folder you are uploading **to** has permission for files to be written to it? If not, use chmod 0777 and test with that.

Comment: Yes it has chmod 775 permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Does your destination folder have proper permissions? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod The directory write to typically needs 775: [What are the proper permissions for an upload folder with PHP/Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990/what-are-the-proper-permissions-for-an-upload-folder-with-php-apache)

Also, do you want users to have direct access to the file? If not you should consider writing the file to a folder that is above your web root directory.

Comment: I double checked the permissions. They are 775. And yes, I do wants users to have direct access to the file. I think the problem may be in the 'move_uploaded_file' line. The database stores the filename in the table and shows it on the form after the upload. But when I check the upload folder, the file is not present.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I happened to be testing locally with a file under php's upload_max_filesize while testing remotely with a file over upload_max_filesize. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30359278/3325776 for more info.