# Can't get file temp name using Wamp Server

Tags: php, file-upload, wamp

I have a simple form used for uploading a video file. The files seem to upload fine, but when I look into destination folder, it isn't there.

So, the problem is moving the uploaded file. Searching where the issue could be, I tried to catch the values of name and temp name of $_FILES and I discovered that the temp name wasn't set. So, in my PHP code:

```
$videoName     = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$videoTempName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

$response['videoName'] = $videoName; // OK, it returns "video.mp4" which is the name of my example file.
$response['videoTempName'] = $videoTempName; // Here is my problem

echo json_encode($response);
```

An important thing that you should know is that I'm using WAMP Server in Windows 10. I suspect that the issue is about there because I've used the same code in remote servers without errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358737/php-file-upload-error-tmp-name-is-empty

Comment: Have you checked `$_FILES['file']['error']`?

Comment: There is a chance you are uploading a file larger than upload_max_filesize (in php.ini)

Comment: @Andreas, no chances. The filesize of my example video is less than 3 MB and the WAMP Server post_max_size is setted in 256 MB

Comment: You should still check the error-param to see if there's something else that happens.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, I did it after your comment, the `$_FILES['file']['error']` returns `1`. What it means?

Comment: That's actually what @Andreas suggested: _"Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini."_.
 Here are all the error codes explained: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: My bad!
I had checked the `post_max_size` but not the `upload_max_filesize` which was setted at 2 MB and my file example is greater than that. So, I changed the `upload_max_filesize` property to 256 MB in the PHP configuration of WAMP Server and it's solved the problem. Thanks @Andreas and @MagnusEriksson !

Answer (score 0):

My bad!
I had checked the `post_max_size` but not the `upload_max_filesize` which was set at 2 MB and my file example is greater than that. So, I changed the `upload_max_filesize` property to 256 MB in the PHP configuration of WAMP Server and it has solved the problem. Thanks Andreas!