# when i try to upload image having file size in MB . Only returns file name but not file size .... (in PHP)

Tags: php, file

Using this code:

```
       <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Image</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <input type="file" name="profile" class="form-control has-feedback-left">
                        <span class="fa fa-image form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <?=showErrors('profile')?>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

When I do:

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

It only returns :-

```
Array
(
    [profile] => Array
        (
            [name] => photos-gallery-canon.jpg
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 1
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: `tmp_name` is empty so there's a chance the file is too large. Check your `upload_max_filesize` ini setting. Also make sure your form is sending multipart data

Comment: Please check the link, this may help you:
**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358737/php-file-upload-error-tmp-name-is-empty**

Comment: Thanks a lot. i just changed upload_max_filesize = 2M to 8M in php.ini file and it works