# Increase "post_max_size" and "upload_max_filesize" only for a specific PHP file, and not for the whole server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, upload

I know, as explained in [PHP file upload error tmp_name is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358737/php-file-upload-error-tmp-name-is-empty), how to increase these values in `php.ini`:

```
upload_max_filesize = 50M 
post_max_size = 50M
```

However, how to enable such settings only for one site / one `.php` script and not globally for all the PHP sites hosted with the same Apache server?

**Is there a way to put this is a local configuration, such as `.htaccess`, and not globally?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [directives page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php), there's a column "Changeable". This shows how it's possible to change each setting, e.g only in php.ini, or with .htaccess or ini_set etc.

An explanation of each possible mode is [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php).

For both `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`, the mode is `PHP_INI_PERDIR`.

> Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini (since PHP 5.3)

So yes, you can use entries in .htaccess files for both:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
php_value post_max_size 50M
```