# $_FILES["imagefile"]["name"] return name but $_FILES["imagefile"]["tmp_name"] return null value?

Tags: php

In my case i was include enctype on myform like

```
<form id="product_add" name="product_add" accept-charset="utf-8" action="product_add_inter.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

then my input type file is

```
<input name="imagefile" class="form-control" type="file"   />
```

Problem is in server side i need to upload my image to distination folder.I was tried to get file from form using

```
$_FILES["imagefile"]["name"]
```

its worked and returned name of my image. But when i get the file using temp_name it return null values.

```
$_FILES["imagefile"]["tmp_name"]
```

how can i solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to see the upload error:

```
print_r($_FILES['imagefile]['error']);
```

The `error code 6` means that there is `no tmp directory`. Go to your `php.ini` and post whats behind that variable:

```
upload_tmp_dir =
```

Comment: it returns the value as 6

Comment: Please post the line `upload_tmp_dir` of your `php.ini` file.

Comment: upload_tmp_dir =empty

Comment: post_max_size = 8M

Comment: upload_max_size = 2M

Comment: Try to set this: `upload_tmp_dir = /tmp` and restart your php interpreter. The /tmp folder must be writeable by the webservers user/group.

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure that PHP is configured to allow file uploads.
In your "php.ini" file, search for the file_uploads directive, and set it to On:

```
file_uploads = On
```

Also did you check like that

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($_FILES);echo '</pre>';
```

and see the result. Are you getting file array and tmp_name?
check your php.ini file for file upload settings.

php.ini setting

Change the upload_max_filesize=2M to 8M

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 8M 

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 8M
```

Here is also solution 
[PHP file upload error tmp_name is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358737/php-file-upload-error-tmp-name-is-empty)

Comment: Array
(
    [imagefile] => Array
        (
            [name] => sw.jpeg
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 6
            [size] => 0
        )

)

Comment: Hi updated my answer kindly visit the link and you will get your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have Checked your Code and its absolutly working fine

```
<?php
echo $_FILES["imagefile"]["name"];
?>
<form id="product_add" name="product_add" accept-charset="utf-8" action="Check.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="imagefile" class="form-control" type="file"   />
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

Please 
Check If phpinfo(given below) whether "file_uploads" is ON and upload_max_filesize

```
<?php
echo phpinfo();
?>
```