# Uploading not working

Tags: php, uploading

I have a script:

```
if(isset($_FILES['file_upload']) && $_FILES['file_upload']['error'] != 4) {
                    if(!file_exists('./Hier_je_files/'.$_FILES['file_upload']['name'])) {
                          if($_FILES['file_upload']['error'] > 0) {
                            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$_FILES['file_upload']['error'].'")</script>';
                          } else {
                            chmod("./Hier_je_files/", 0755);
                            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_upload"]["tmp_name"], "./Hier_je_files/" . $_FILES["file_upload"]["name"]);
                            $_POST['bestand'] = $_FILES["file_upload"]["name"];
                            chmod("./Hier_je_files/".$_POST['bestand'], 0755);
                          }
                    } else {
                        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert(\'Bestandnaam helaas bezet!\')</script>';
                    }
                } else {
                    chmod("./Hier_je_files/".$_POST['bestand'], 0755);
                }
```

And I get this error:

> Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: Operation not permitted in
>   /home/remon/domains/remondb.eu/public_html/Handeler/control.php on
>   line 347
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(./Hier_je_files/download_r2.png)
>   [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission
>   denied in
>   /home/remon/domains/remondb.eu/public_html/Handeler/control.php on
>   line 348
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to
>   move '/tmp/phpMuFzaS' to './Hier_je_files/download_r2.png' in
>   /home/remon/domains/remondb.eu/public_html/Handeler/control.php on
>   line 348
>
> Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: No such file or directory in
>   /home/remon/domains/remondb.eu/public_html/Handeler/control.php on
>   line 350
>
> Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for
>   ./Hier_je_files/download_r2.png in
>   /home/remon/domains/remondb.eu/public_html/Handeler/control.php on
>   line 358

By other people this script works fine, does my host blocks uploading or is the script bad?

Comment: Smells like a permission issue. Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990/what-are-the-proper-permissions-for-an-upload-folder-with-php-apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user that PHP is running as on your server does not have permission to use `chmod`. Consequently, you don't have permission to write to the file. You should probably not use `chmod` in your script anyway, and it seems your host does not allow it.

Rather, you should ensure that the folder you are attempting to upload to AND the folder that files upload to temporarily have the permissions you show above (0755).