# Save uploaded file to documents folder on Mac

Tags: php, macos

I want to save uploaded files into the documents path on my Mac.

I tried it like this:

```
  move_uploaded_file("/Documents/".$_FILES["myflies"]["name"]);
```

But this is not working. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Is your webserver running locally on your mac? So you are trying to move something that is on your mac already via a form?

Comment: i used like this: move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myflies"]["tmp_name"],$foldername.$_FILES["myflies"]["name']); to save into  Web server.it works.but i want to save it to Documents in finder on Mac

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990/what-are-the-proper-permissions-for-an-upload-folder-with-php-apache