# what's wrong with my file upload coding in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-3

I need to upload file using **CI** (version 3.0)
this is my **`view`** file
`image_gallery.php`

```
<?php 
  echo form_open_multipart('gallery_control');
  echo form_upload('userfile', 'upload_image');
  echo form_submit('submit', 'Upload');
  echo form_close();
?>
```

this my **`controllers`** file
`gallery_control.php`

```
class Gallery_control extends CI_Controller 
{

  function index()
  {

    $this->load->model('gallery_model');

    if($this->input->post('upload'))
    {
        $this->gallery_model->do_upload();
    }
    else
    {
        //$this->gallery_model->display_errors();
    }
    //here I used template to call view file
    $data['main_content'] = 'image_gallery';
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
  }
}
```

this my **`models`** file
`gallery_model.php`

```
class Gallery_model extends CI_Model 
{
  var $gallery_path;

 public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

     //$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url')); #autoloaded from config file
       $this->gallery_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../uploaded_images');
    }


  public function do_upload()
  {
    $config = array(
            'allowed_types' => 'gif|png|jpeg',
            'upload_path' => $this->gallery_path,
            'max_size' => 2000
        );

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $this->upload->do_upload();
  }
}
```

this is my coding path after run this. I'm not getting image in `uploaded_images` folder which I created out site the `application` folder and there is no error showing it is returning to index page (`image_gallery.php`). whats wrong with my coding please help me?

Comment: Do you have permissions to write in that external folder?

Comment: where I can check the permission and how do I check please?

Comment: This one has some nice answers, but there might be even better ones: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990/what-are-the-proper-permissions-for-an-upload-folder-with-php-apache

Comment: First I'd try to upload in the directory where your PHP file is, just for testing, and it that works, check the permission link above.

Comment: from your link I could not get well explanation about my problem since i'm a new to this field   If you can please help me.

Comment: That (and similar) links will help you better than I can. Test if you can upload it to your project dir.

Comment: CI3 requires First_capital file names of classes. Use it for controllers, models, libraries and hooks.