# file_put_contents: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, windows-10

I am currently working on a project that writes to a file based on your input. This works perfectly fine on my localhost, but when I try this project on my college server - it just doesn't work.

```
$ret = file_put_contents('paameldinger.dat', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

This line is supposted to return true, but returns false on the college server.

> Warning: file_put_contents(paameldinger.dat): failed to open stream: Permission denied

This is the message I am getting through my browser.

Comment: file_put_contents need write permission on that folder https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990/what-are-the-proper-permissions-for-an-upload-folder-with-php-apache

Comment: Do you have Linux/Apache server or a Windows/IIS?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that you have permission to access the file `paameldinger.dat`

**STEP 1** If you are on linux, you can check it by:

```
ls -l
```

command from the directory of the file (on windows you may use CMDER editor to execute the above command).

**STEP 2:** You can change the permission of the file by:

```
chmod 777 paameldinger.dat
```